# Save byte array to file

Tags: c#, file, stream, save, byte

I have a byte array (an IEnumerable actually), and I need to save it to a new file containing this data.

How do I do that?

I found some answers telling how to create a MemoryStream from that, but still can't save it to a brand new file.

Answer (score 367, accepted):

You can use:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("Foo.txt", arrBytes); // Requires System.IO
```

If you have an enumerable and not an array, you can use:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("Foo.txt", arrBytes.ToArray()); // Requires System.Linq
```

Answer (score 27):

You can use [File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx)

Comment: Please avoid using "only link" answers.